# FTPD Server Issue

Tags: server, xampp

So I am trying to use my xampp server and for the life of me can't understand why my ProFTPD will not turn on. It only became cause for concern when I saw the word "bogon" in the application log. Can anyone translate to me what the application log means and maybe how I go about troubleshooting the problem ?

```
Stopping all servers...
Stopping Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd stopped
Stopping MySQL Database...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh : mysql stopped
Starting ProFTPD...
Exit code: 8
Stdout:
Checking syntax of configuration file
proftpd config test fails, aborting
Stderr:
bogon proftpd[3948]: warning: unable to determine IP address of 'bogon'
bogon proftpd[3948]: error: no valid servers configured
bogon proftpd[3948]: Fatal: error processing configuration file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/proftpd.conf'
```

Comment: it seems like that you have used some wrong configuration into the proftpd.conf file, have you used bogon spell into host or ip address, please chekcout it, Might be it will help to you

Comment: I have not used a "bogon spell" or am I aware of what that is. Could this possibly mean that there is a security problem?

Comment: application log means "An application log is a file of events that are logged by a software application. It contains errors, informational events and warnings. The format and content of an application log are determined by the developer of the software program, rather than the OS."